# With docker - gunicorn multiple worker vs replica

Tags: python, gunicorn, wsgi

As I know, it's recommended to run single process in one container.
But usually I run multiple workers when I use gunicorn as wsgi.
Is it better to run multiple replica of gunicorn rather than single replica of multiple worker gunicorn?